# How to make a reactive copy from props with Vue3/TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I take a value (in this case, an object) outside of the props it was provided in and place it into a reactive variable without affecting the original props?

To give more context, I am attempting to programmatically generate a Naive UI Form, which requires an object variable that has the values of all of the fields used in the form as key-value pairs.

Example:

```
const formValues = ref({
  email: '',
  password: '',
})
```

These values are reactive, thanks to the "ref". My issue is getting the object inside of my props, which is identical to the object inside of the above `ref`, and actually making that reactive.

Here's my code:

```
const props = defineProps<{ options: Model }>()
const { options } = toRefs(props)
// The above works fine when I want to use something
// like options.name inside of a component

console.log(options.value.form.values) // Prints out the correct object.
const values = ref(options.value.form.values)
console.log(values.value) // Prints out a <proxy>, <target> Object, and the fields remain unreactive.
```

I am at a complete loss with this one. I have also attempted copying the object from inside of the `options`, but that has the same result.

Quick edit: I am using the `<script setup>` syntax.

Comment: It would help to see an example of how you're passing in this prop, and where you are expecting reactivity. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Agree with Tony. Right now it is unclear what you are trying to do. Reproducible example would help a lot...